# Converting from docker-compose to Kubernetes - how to deal with volumes on local

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, persistent-volumes

I'm try to get my local development environment converted from `docker-compose` to a flavour of lightweight Kubernetes, since our production environments are all Kubernetes (like). With the help of [Kompose](https://kompose.io) I could convert my settings. The part however I struggle with is the conversion of Docker volumes to a local developer machine Volume and Volume claim. Most examples I found cover drivers for S3 or NFS, which isn't what my development laptop offers.

So when I have in my `docker-compose.yml` a setting like this, what's the local development equivalent in k8s?

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  my_test:
    image: "myregistry.com/my_test"
    container_name: "demo"
    hostname: "demo.acme.local"
    stop_grace_period: 120s
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - my_vol:/local/my_app
volumes:
  my_vol:
    name: "/local/containers/my_app"
    external: false
```

I'm "only" looking for the volume part. The rest seems clear.
Help is appreciated

Comment: there's a link to hostPath for a single node cluster: https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/kubernetes-volume-hostpath-explained-with-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions (`hostpath` and `emptydir`) you found looks good.

Here you have documentations to both ones:

---

> A [`hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's filesystem into your Pod.

To the required `path` property, you can also specify a `type` for a `hostPath` volume.

> **NOTE**:
> HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a best practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a HostPath volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required file or directory, and mounted as **ReadOnly**.

- [*hostPath configuration example*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath-configuration-example)

---

> An [`emptyDir`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) volume is first created when a Pod is assigned to a node, and exists as long as that Pod is running on that node.

`EmptyDir` volume is initially empty. All containers in the pod have permissions in the `emptyDir` volume to read and write the same files, despite possibility of diffrent localisations of that volume (it can be mounted at the same or different paths in each container).

In case the Pod is removed from a node for any reason, the data in the `emptyDir` is deleted *permanently*.

> Depending on your environment, `emptyDir` volumes are stored on whatever medium that backs the node such as disk or SSD, or network storage.

- [*emptyDir configuration example*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir-configuration-example)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the **host path** or you can use the **emptydir** that's on you

Probably **hostpath** would be a better option.

If you are planning to use the **minikube** you can also check out the **PV** and **PVC** option which is mostly for the **persistence** storage in Kubernetes.

**Hostpath** : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath-configuration-example

**emptydir** : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir